# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, sockets, scapy, callable

This is my code:

```
import scapy.all
from scapy.all import *


def create_ip_packet(my_req):
    ip_packet = IP(dst=my_req)
    return ip_packet
```

my_req is a simple string as "www.google.com"
and I'm trying to create a packet with an IP layer that sets the source address as the above string

The full ERROR is:
in create_ip_packet
ip_packet = IP(dst=my_req)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I tried different ways of importation found on Google but it still doesn't work. Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). E.g. What is `IP()`, what is the input to the method, what is the complete error? ...

Comment: To creates an IP packet with destination, we have to use "IP()", I tried to create a packet with an IP address that contains a certain source address that I extracted from an HTTP request (a simple site string), 
It does not recognize IP as an action even though, I did import  socket

Comment: That doesn't help. But I guess you use `scapy.all.IP`. However, still need input and complete error...

Comment: The error likely lies in code that you haven't posted. Perhaps you assigned an IP address to `IP`.  Why not provide a [mcve]? Without that, we can do no more than guess.

Comment: the input is a  simple string as "www.google.com" 
the complete error is:
..... line 26, in create_ip_packet return ip_packet TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: That isn't the full traceback. Please put the full traceback in the question itself.

Comment: I added the full error to the question, Is it OK?

Comment: The error says "You wrote something like `IP = "..."`". You should consider that Python might be right about that, and look to see where you might have made that kind of mistake.

Comment: My guess it that if you replace `IP(dst=my_req)` by `scapy.all.IP(dst=my_req)` then the error disappears. One of the reasons that `import *` is discouraged is that it is too easy for it to create name clashes. You have almost certainly named a string `IP` somewhere else in your code and have just such a name clash.

Comment: I changed to this scapy.all.IP(dst=my_req), and it works.Thanks!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.